# Using cluster.stats with hclust

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hclust

I have a problem using cluster.stats on two different hclust clusters. Is that not possible?

I am on Version 0.99.491 – © 2009-2015 RStudio, Inc.
with below packages installed:

```
mylib <- "/Users/Klaus/R Packages/"; mylib
install.packages("NbClust",lib=mylib)
install.packages("modeltools",lib=mylib)
install.packages("flexclust",lib=mylib)
install.packages("RTextTools",lib=mylib) # Amazon's default machine image uses the Atlas BLAS. R points to that when installed with all defaults, but RTextTools expects the ordinary BLAS. 
install.packages("mclust",lib=mylib)
install.packages("fpc",lib=mylib)

library("NbClust",lib=mylib)
library("modeltools",lib=mylib)
library("flexclust",lib=mylib)
library("cluster",lib=mylib)
library("mclust",lib=mylib)
library("fpc",lib=mylib)
```

I am creating these clusters:

```
data(nutrient, package="flexclust")
row.names(nutrient) <- tolower(row.names(nutrient))
nutrient.scaled <- scale(nutrient)
d_eucli <- dist(nutrient.scaled,"euclidean")
fit.single <- hclust(d_eucli, method="single")
fit.average <- hclust(d_eucli, method="average")
```

But when using cluster.stats on them I get an error:

```
cluster.stats(d_eucli, fit.single$cluster, fit.average$cluster)
```

Error (In Danish setup):

```
Fejl i `[<-`(`*tmp*`, j, i, value = Inf) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Advarselsbeskeder:
1: I max(clustering) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: I cluster.stats(d_eucli, fit.single$cluster, fit.average$cluster) :
  clustering renumbered because maximum != number of clusters
3: I min(bv) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: I min(sij) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

hclust will compute a dendrogram, not a partitioning.

To do that latter step, use `cutree`. Then you should be able to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work , I tried it myself:

```
fit.single <- hclust(d_eucli, method="single")

fit.average <- hclust(d_eucli, method="average")

cut.single <- cutree(fit.single, k=3)
```

*you should specify the number of cluster (K) if you know it or based on others validation test*

```
cut.average <- cutree(fit.average, k=3)

cluster.stats(d_eucli, cut.single, cut.average)
```